# Django ORM: how to filter one model with a subquery on a related model

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble referencing outer fields from a django subquery in a way that would be pretty easy to do in SQL. I have these two models:

```
class Modem(models.Model):
    mac = Models.LowerCaseCharField

class DHCPEvent(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField() # date released
    modem = models.ForeignKey(Modem)
    ip = models.LowerCaseCharField()
```

The time window of when an IP is assigned to a given modem A is: [timestamp when IP assigned to modem A, timestamp when IP is assigned to another modem). I want to be able to query for all IP assignments to a specific modem overlapping a search time window (modem, from_date, to_date -> [ips]).

To do this, I believe I need to find DHCPEvents assigned to a modem before the time window ends, and then, for each one, confirm there is no DHCPEvent for its IP assigned elsewhere before the search time window starts. This defines that the IP-to-modem assignment overlaps with the search window. But I am not sure how to do this in Django. What I have so far is this:

```
Modem.objects.filter(
        dhcpevent__ip=Subquery(
            DHCPEvent.objects.filter(
                ip=OuterRef('dhcpevent__ip'),
                timestamp__gt=OuterRef('dhcpevent__timestamp'),
                timestamp__lte=to_date)))
```

There are two issues:

1. It is throwing "ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery." It seems to be inside a subquery to me.
2. I need the OuterRefs to only look at the DHCPEvent first referenced in the second line, not every DHCPEvent attached to this Modem. But I don't know how to express this.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I have now written this query in SQL which might clear up what I'm trying to achieve in Django a lot:

```
select 
    *
from 
    "MODEM" modem
        inner join "DHCPEVENT" dhcp_event_assign 
            on modem."ID" = dhcp_event_assign."MODEM_ID"
where
    modem."ID" = %(id)s
    dhcp_event_assign."TIMESTAMP" <= %(to_date)s and
    not exists(
        select 
            *
        from 
            "DHCPEVENT" dhcp_event_next
        where 
            dhcp_event_next."REMOTE_ADDRESS" = dhcp_event_assign."REMOTE_ADDRESS"
            and dhcp_event_next."TIMESTAMP" > dhcp_event_assign."TIMESTAMP"
            and dhcp_event_next."TIMESTAMP" <= %(from_date)s
            and not ( dhcp_event_next."MODEM_ID" = modem."ID" )
        )
```

Comment: Im not sure if I understood your question. But what is stopping you from using `Modem.objects.filter(dhcpevent__ip=the_ip, dhcp__timestamp__gt=timestamp, dhcp__timestamp__lte=to_date)`?

Comment: That doesn't work because if a DHCP lease starts before the search query time window and ends after it, this query won't find it because, even though the lease window overlaps, no actual events do.

Comment: But subquery wont solve anything in this case. You are just doing a query inside another one. If you went to insure you dont miss any dhcp leases, you need to look into a locking mechanism which will stop leasing ips until your query is done. That way is easier and more accurate imo.

Comment: I think there might be a misunderstanding - are you talking about locking as in searching atomically? Or am I missing something?

The issue with that query is that if I have, e.g., a lease assignment to modem A on 8/1, then an assignment to another modem on 8/30, and search for modem A leases from 8/10 to 8/15, your query will not find the lease, even though it overlaps the time window. Hence why (I think) I need to subquery the DHCPEvent table to look ahead to the next event for that IP.

Comment: No, I mean it in a way that before you start your filter query, disable dont allow any IP leasing until you are done, then once you are done with getting results, resume leasing IPs.

Comment: Yeah, that isn't the issue I have with it. Does my last comment make sense, or can I clarify it in some way? That's an example of the given query providing a false negative.